# rspec test not passing. use of dynamic data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, testing, rubygems, rspec

I have an rspec test that was written for an email being sent. it contains a dynamic field that's filled in with the org name of the user in the application. I changed the text from one name to the other and update the spec file to reflect the difference but now it won't pass. Here's the test

```
require "spec_helper"

describe OrgMemberMailer do

context "when an invite email gets sent" do
before(:each) do
  member = Factory(:organization_membership)
  @email = OrgMemberMailer.invite(member, 'samsdungeonsanddragonsguild.com').deliver
end
it "should be delivered successfully" do
  ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.should_not be_empty
  @email.from.should == ["invite@domain.com"]
  @email.subject.should == "SocialNetwork - invitation to join <ORG>"
  @email.encoded.should =~ /You have been invited to join <ORG> on SocialNetwork/
  @email.encoded.should =~ /samsdungeonsanddragonsguild.com\/organization\/accept/
end

end

end
```

'SocialNetwork' is static text but  is replaced by data both in the mailer.rb and hard coded into the rspec file. I've just used  as a placeholder above.

When I run the test, I get:

```
OrgMemberMailer when an invite email gets sent should be delivered successfully
     Failure/Error: @email.subject.should == "SocialNetwork - invitation to join <ORG>"
       expected: "SocialNetwork - invitation to join <ORG>"
            got: "SocialNetwork - invitation to join <ORG>" (using ==)
 # ./spec/org_member_mailer_spec.rb:13:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

To me, everything looks fine. I see no reason why it shouldn't pass.

Comment: Seems there was a lower case letter hiding in the <ORG> specified. Then the line:

    @email.encoded.should =~ /You have been invited to join <ORG> on SocialNetwork/

had to be changed to:

    @email.encoded.match(/You have been invited to join <ORG> on SocialNetwork/).should_not be_nil

Now it all passes! 
YAY!!

Answer (score 1):

try should eql instead should ==